# Balancing torques in a free body diagram: What point should they be in equilibrium about

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, free-body-diagram

I have an object that is mounted securely so that it cannot move, which is then loaded by an external force. I would like to determine the forces acting on the mount points. Since the object is not accelerating rotationally, I know the torques must be in equilibrium. My question is: about what point are they in equilibrium? Would it be the center of mass of the object?

Comment: About _every point_ in the object the net torque will be zero

Comment: Every point outside the object as well.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of torques as seen from any point relative to the object, which isn't changing its angular velocity, should add up to zero. In order to solve for all reaction forces for such a static equilibrium you have to pick the same number of points as you have mounting points.

When you are calculating things by hand it is often easier to pick each point on top of each mounting point

Answer (score 0):

Since it's in rotational equilibrium, the torques will sum to zero about any axis you choose.

Sometimes there is an obvious choice of axis because you can ignore any forces that pass directly through the axis and using that one will make the analysis simpler.

But doing the analysis about some other axis is exactly as valid.